# compare 2 data frames and pick up the inconsistent rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say there are two data frames as followed:

```
test.df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), nr = rnorm(5))
test.df2 <- rbind(test.df1, data.frame(id = c(6:8), nr = rnorm(3)))
```

Obviously, test.df2 has 3 rows of data, which are not present in test.df1. How can I quickly pick up these additional data. The end effect I wish to have is to obtain a data frame, which contains the 3 rows that are only contained in test.df2. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure, maybe `library(dplyr) ; anti_join(test.df2, test.df1, by = "id")`?

Comment: it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `nr` values that are only present in `test.df2` and not in `test.df1`. You can try

```
test.df2[!test.df2$nr %in% test.df1$nr, ]

#   id         nr
#6  6 -0.3708036
#7  7 -0.4739193
#8  8  0.3420794
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!